# i need to turn an integer of coordinates in a list that need to be in a certain order into a iterable so the turtle can goto those coordinates

Tags: python, coordinates, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
listplaceloc = doornum-1
coordinatelist[listplaceloc] = turtle.pos()
coordinatelist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
coordlistnum = 0    
turtle.goto(coordinatelist[coordlistnum])
coordlistnum +=1
turtle.pendown()
turtle.color("black")
while coordlistnum!= 24:
    iter (coordinatelist[coordlistnum])
    turtle.goto(coordinatelist[coordlistnum])
    coordlistnum += 1
```

i have tried the iter function, but it said it couldn't be iter'ed

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you're simply trying to iterate over `coordinatelist`, which you're doing already.
You can simply get rid of the `iter (coordinatelist[coordlistnum])` because you're already *iterating* through the list in a while loop by implementing a counter and incrementing it.

```py
coordlistnum = 0 
...
coordinatelist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
while coordlistnum!= 24:
    turtle.goto(coordinatelist[coordlistnum])
    coordlistnum += 1
```

This means you'll be calling all elements of `coordinatelist` until you reach element number 24 (elements 1...23, because you've incremented the `coordlistnum` once before going into the loop and because once you increment it to 24 you'll exit the loop)

`iter()` returns an iterator object, which could be valid too, you'll simply have to call `next()` on the iterator and catch the exception like so:

```py
coordinatelistIter = iter(coordinatelist)
try:
    while True:
        coordinates = next(coordinatelistIter)
        ...
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

You're probably better off with a simple for loop while slicing the list to stop at the 23rd element

```py
for coordinate in coordinatelist[:24]:
   ...
```

Or enumerate and use the index and the value and break (exit the loop) once you reach the required index:

```py
for index, value in enumerate(coordinatelistIter):
   if index > 23:
      break
   turtle.goto(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `goto()` requires both an X and Y coordinate, the only way I can interpret your code fragment is that you want to move:

```
(1, 2) -> (2, 3) -> (3, 4) -> ... -> (22, 23) -> (23, 24)
```

If that's the case, we do so as follows:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

coordinatelist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.penup()

coordlistnum = 0

while coordlistnum < len(coordinatelist) - 1:
    turtle.goto(coordinatelist[coordlistnum:coordlistnum+2])
    turtle.pendown()
    coordlistnum += 1

screen.exitonclick()
```

If that's not the case, you need to further clarify your question.